# How do I import an npm CSS package into Codepen Project?

Tags: html, css, import, frameworks, codepen

I'm attempting to import an atomic CSS framework - http://buildwithbeard.com/ - into a Codepen Project. I'm able to successfully get most of the functionality through simply linking it in my HTML like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/beardcss/dist/beard.css">
```

However, in order to add new helpers (specifically, color helpers!), I need to import it into a .sass file as explained on [this page](http://buildwithbeard.com/installation/).

But, because it's telling me to install it via NPM, I can't figure out a way to get the proper files into the proper place into my CodePen project.

([Here's a link to my CodePen Project](https://codepen.io/kristinalustig/project/editor/ZyMxGa#).)

[This guide](https://codepen.io/alexzaworski/post/faking-node-modules-in-projects) on how to fake node modules in CodePen assumes a .js file - I can't figure out which files I need in which folder in order to successfully use BeardCSS in this CodePen Project.

How can I import and use BeardCSS in my CodePen Project?

Comment: You can use codesandbox and load the npm package :) [here's a quick example using beard there](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn5y9ylx0l) (with a scss file you can edit and see on your browser)